# time function in c keeps returning -1

Tags: c

Hi I hava a little problem because the function `time()` keeps returning -1 is there any posible way to fix this?

I tried:

```
time_t start, end;
start = time(NULL);
//do something
end = time(NULL);
```

But when I debug both have the value -1.
 and I tried:

```
time_t start, end;
time(&start);
// do something
time(&end);
```

But in this case both values stay 0.

Comment: and how do you check the return value?

Comment: I use them in `if (difftime(mod_end, mod_start) < TCK_WAIT_TIME_SEC)` but I check the values in the debuger

Comment: What does it print if you do this:  `start = time(NULL); if (start==(time_t)-1) perror("time failed"); else printf("start=%ld\n",start);`

Comment: have you tried a minimal working example of this? and just print out the content of your start-value?

Comment: What C compiler? The function works as expected in gcc 4.9 (with both ways of calling it).

Comment: Have you checked `errno` value ?

Comment: @dbush, when I run the programm with this code my IDE crashes. But since I'm working with Simplicity Studio and this programm works on a micro processor, I doubt thath printf will work because I already tried it with printf but my IDE didn't show it anywhere.

Comment: does the code your running contain: `#include <time.h>`  Is the function: `time()` implemented in the libc library on the target microprocessor?  Is the RTC (real time clock) hardware accessible on the target microprocessor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly valid, according to ISO C, for `time()` to return `-1` if it cannot establish the time. From `ISO C11 7.27.2.4 The time function /3` (though this behaviour has been around for a long time):

> The **`time`** function returns the implementation’s best approximation to the current calendar time. The value **`(time_t)(-1)`** is returned if the calendar time is not available.

Given that you're working with Simplicity Studio, a package frequently used for embedded systems, it's possible your target environment may not be able to establish the calendar time (if, for example, it does not have a real-time clock to query).